# Bigquery Materialized view on partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

I'm not able to create materialized view over a partitioned table, even though I have added partition filter in the query itself.

[image]

Source Table has partition column ts:timestamp, partitioned by date(ts)
[image]

Query for materialized view:

```
create materialized view `materialized_view_1`
partition by Date(ts)
as
select Date(ts) date, count(*) count from `source_table`
where date(ts) > "2021-01-01"
group by 1
```

Error -

> Table `source_table` requires a partition filter. Materialized views over a table that requires a partition filter must have a filter over the table's partitioning column or output the column.

Comment: Partitioning column of the materialized view should match partitioning column or the pseudo-column (if ingestion time partition is used)of the base table, or be a TIMESTAMP_TRUNC over it. Please see here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views. Can you please change your query to below and try, create materialized view `materialized_view_1`
partition by Date(ts)
as
select ts, count(*) count from `source_table`
where date(ts) > "2021-01-01"
group by 1

Comment: I see same error.

Comment: I created a test table which is partitioned by day on timestamp column and also partition filter is required. I ran below query and it did create the materialized view.create or replace materialized view `project.dataset.materialized_view_2`
partition by date(ts)
as
select ts, count(*) count from `project.dataset.test_partition`
where date(ts) > "2021-01-01"
group by 1. I did not get any error but though the materialized view created is day partitioned on ts column, I see it did created with partition filter as required.